# Can the same hero get hit by two McCree high noon bullets?

Tags: overwatch

So Mercy, Roadhog and McCree walk into a saloon. And Roadhog is between both of them, and McCree goes all high-noon on them, but shoots without charging enough to one-shot roadhog.

Does McCree lock onto both? If so, when he shoots, and the first shot doesnt kill Roadhog, does Roadhog also get hit by the second? If not, what if Mercy just walked right behind Roadhog at the last second (after McCree starts firing but before its her turn to die, which I've seen happen with heros going behind walls just at the last second)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes***

If you walk into the direct line of fire between McCree and one of his locked in targets, you will intercept the bullet meant for the person behind you.

McCree's Deadeye is a hitscan attack that charges at a rate of 170 damage per second.

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FVPYEaIwuA) at 0:11, you can see a Roadhog with full lock (600+ damage) survive Deadeye because a Reinhardt walks in front.

While this does not directly prove the point, as Reinhardt gets one-shot by the 600 damage bullet meant for Roadhog, and only one bullet is fired, if Reinhardt had spent any more time in front of Roadhog, a second lock on would start for the Reinhardt, and both would hit him.

I'll back this up with a .gif showing this when I return from work.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that Roadhog would survive in this scenario because *heroes never die*.

Comment: "Bread established"

That's what Mercy says, right?

Comment: @KizTrap are you still at work? Someone needs to call OSHA and report your employer!

Comment: @DoktorJ Yes. Send help in the form of food, Overwatch and blankets! Nah, I just forgot about this :P

Answer (score 0):

Every hero McCree locks on gets one shot. THe longer McCree charges, the higher damage he'll do (up to 1040 dmg per all 6 seconds charging). If he charges for 3 seconds that will kill Mercy but leave RoadHog at very low HP.

If Mercy goes behind Roadhog and he (Roadhog) doesn't die, then Mercy will live another day too.

Comment: So if there's only one hero, then only one bullet hits, and the rest are just wasted?

Comment: McCree only shoots one shot per target. If 2 targets are valid Deadeye shots, he will go down to 4/6 ammo remaining, the other 4 do not get shot. He always reloads fully upon activation of Deadeye too.